# Is my schema for a Discussion forum using Cassandra optimum or has a scope for improvement?

Tags: performance, schema, nosql, cassandra, query-performance

I am designing a **Discussion Forum** for my app which has following primary objects:

- Image
- Video
- Text
- Audio

The owner can start a discussion in context of any of the above object. Based on user permissions, she can respond to a post up to level 3. The owner of the Post can block a user from responding and a user can unsubscribe to a Post. User can also upvote/downvote a Post.
Consider the following example in context of a Video:

- Post

  - Response 1

    - Comment 1
  - Response 2

    - Comment 2

My potential DB `SELECT` queries are as follows:

1. Get all/limited Posts of an Object.
2. Get all/limited Responses of a Post.
3. Get all/limited Comments of a Response.

I have come up with the following schema:

[image]

Here **K** means Partition Key and **C** means Clustering Key.

Is this schema optimum for the current use-case or there is a scope for improvement?